# node-superagent displaying unwanted message during mocha testing - how to remove?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Mocha is displaying this message when I run tests:

**CMD:**

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2018:09:54:01 +0000] "DELETE /reviews/12 HTTP/1.1" 500 21 "-" "node-superagent/1.2.0"

**Test:**

```
  it('should not delete anything and get status 500 for incorrect id', function (done) {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/reviews')
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    chai.request(app)
                        .delete('/reviews/12')
                        .end(function (err, res) {
                            expect(res).to.have.status(500);
                            done();
                        });
                });
        });
```

Comment: That's generated by the logger of your Express app. It might be possible to disable it during testing, but you should add the logger configuration/setup to your question.

Comment: "test": "set NODE_ENV=test && mocha test/routes/review-test.js" in package. if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    app.use(logger('dev'));
} in app.js  - None of which work

Answer (score 0):

That line is generated by an Express logger middleware.

To disable it, you can test if the app is being run in a test situation, and not load it:

```
// `app` is an Express app
if (app.get('env') !== 'test') {
  app.use(morgan(...)); // or whatever logger you're using
}
```

This code goes into the main application file, *not* the test file. It only works if the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `test` (which it is, judging by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152054/node-superagent-displaying-unwanted-message-during-mocha-testing-how-to-remove?noredirect=1#comment93195143_53152054)).

Comment: This was the problem -  app.use(morgan('combined'))